# Difficulty installing psycopg2 on El Capitan

Tags: python, macos, postgresql

After installing El Capitan with "SIP" I've had trouble with both homebrew and psycopg2.

After being asleep my Mac would randomly refuse to allow login requiring a reboot first. The Apple Capture Data app pointed to homebrew as the culprit. There have been some fixes on internet that will allow the user write to /usr/local if homebrew is located there. see http://digitizor.com/fix-homebrew-permissions-osx-el-capitan/

The remaining, related,problem is "How to install psycopg2". There are a few fixes on the internet but they don't fix the problem for me.

I get this at the end of verbose output from **pip install psycopg2**

```
building 'psycopg2._psycopg' extension
  creating build/temp.macosx-10.11-x86_64-3.5
  creating build/temp.macosx-10.11-x86_64-3.5/psycopg
  clang -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes arch x86_64 -DPSYCOPG_DEFAULT_PYDATETIME=1 -DPSYCOPG_VERSION="2.6.1 (dt dec pq3 ext lo64)" -DPG_VERSION_HEX=0x090405 -DHAVE_LO64=1 -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/local/opt/openssl/include -I/usr/local/opt/sqlite/include -I/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.5.1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/include/python3.5m -I. -I/usr/local/Cellar/postgresql/9.4.5_2/include -I/usr/local/Cellar/postgresql/9.4.5_2/include/server -c psycopg/psycopgmodule.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.11-x86_64-3.5/psycopg/psycopgmodule.o

  clang: error: no such file or directory: 'arch'
  clang: error: no such file or directory: 'x86_64'
  error: command 'clang' failed with exit status 1
```

and

```
Command "/usr/local/opt/python3/bin/python3.5 -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/private/var/folders/bj/chzjff753fz0hr1l5r9kcc1c0000gn/T/pip-build-h9jxgxsp/psycopg2/setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /var/folders/bj/chzjff753fz0hr1l5r9kcc1c0000gn/T/pip-2uer9v1a-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in /private/var/folders/bj/chzjff753fz0hr1l5r9kcc1c0000gn/T/pip-build-h9jxgxsp/psycopg2
```

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the first issue, the random need to reboot the system, the difficulty was El Captain's apparent inability to handle more than two bluetooth devices. I was using a touch-pad, mouse and keyboard. Mouse or touch-pad had to go. Problem vanished!

Apple had first advised that homebrew was the problem, then CleanMyMac. Not so!

Second issue still pending ...

Answer (score -2):

You may like using Conda to install pre-compiled psycopg2 instead of immediately dealing with this homebrew issue.

To install Conda:

```
wget https://repo.continuum.io/miniconda/Miniconda3-latest-MacOSX-x86_64.sh
bash Miniconda3-latest-MacOSX-x86_64.sh -b
```

Then, create a Conda environment named 'postgres' with Python 3.5 and psycopg2:

```
conda create -n postgres python=3.5 psycopg2
```

From here, activate this Conda environment with `source activate postgres` and you'll have access to psycopg2.

```
MyMachine:~ username$ source activate postgres
discarding /Users/username/miniconda/bin from PATH
prepending /Users/username/miniconda/envs/postgres/bin to PATH
(postgres)MyMachine:~ username$ python
Python 3.5.0 |Continuum Analytics, Inc.| (default, Sep 13 2015, 10:37:42) 
[GCC 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5577)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import psycopg2
>>> conn = psycopg2.connect("dbname='template1' user='username' host='localhost'")
>>> conn
<connection object at 0x1026143c0; dsn: 'dbname='template1' user='username' host='localhost'', closed: 0>
```

> > > 